# How to import global CSS from JSON in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have something along the lines of

```
  "A": {
    "color": "#FF0000"
  },
  "B": {
    "color": "#006600"
  },
```

being returned by an API. I want to transform this into CSS, such as

```
.A { color : #FF0000}
.B {...}
```

and then load it for global use in my application. How can I do this? All the other solutions I've found require loading from a file, or specify that you apply `cssFile.class` property. There are an unknown amount of styles in the JSON.

Comment: Just an fyi, but `.A { "color" : "FF0000"}` is not valid CSS. It would need to be `.A { color: #FF0000;}`. How extensive are these style rules supplied by the API?  The data needs to be converted and if it's just simply converting the string `"FF0000"` to the color `#FF0000`, it should be easy.  Anything more involved and it'll be significantly harder.

Comment: @JosephMarikle you're right, I've fixed that. The style rules will be pretty simple, but there can be any number of them.

Comment: Have you taken into account that there can only be one style rule for `.A`?  You can't have two properties of an object with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Principally, you'll want to use `for..in` so you can iterate over the object properties.  You'll do this for both the classes and the class properties.  Then it's just a matter of building out the right syntax; adding it to a `<style>` element, which we'll create programmatically; and injecting that into the document `<head>`.

```js
var data = {
  "A": {
    "color": "#FF0000"
  },
  "B": {
    "color": "#006600"
  }
}, rules = [];


for(var i in data) {
  var rule = `.${i}{`;
  for(var j in data[i]) {
    rule += `${j}:${data[i][j]};`;
  }
  rule += `}`;
  rules.push(rule);
}

var injectedStyles = document.createElement('style');
injectedStyles.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
injectedStyles.innerHTML = rules.join('');

document.head.appendChild(injectedStyles);
```

```html
<p class="A">This should be red</p>
<p class="B">This should be dark green</p>
<p class="C">This should be the default text color</p>
```